# Transform next posts link in button

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have this link for the next posts in my html theme:

```
<ul class="navigation">
   <li class="previous">
     <a href="previous.html" class="page-elements-title">prev</a>
   </li>
   <li class="next">
     <a href="next.html" class="page-elements-title">next</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS transforms this link into a nice button.

Now i want to apply this code into a wordpress theme. I tried:

```
<ul class="navigation">
   <li class="previous">
     <a href="<?php echo get_next_posts_link(); ?>" class="page-elements-title">prev</a>
   </li>
   <li class="next">
     <a href="<?php echo get_previous_posts_link(); ?>" class="page-elements-title">next</a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

But it doesn't work! How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
previous_post_link and next_post_link is Deprecated
```

so instead of this use following

```
<?php previous_post(); ?>    <?php next_post(); ?>
```

refer codex [Next_and_Previous_Links](http://codex.wordpress.org/Next_and_Previous_Links)

Comment: Nevermind, i got it! I just put a 'S'! `<?php previous_postS(); ?>`